# Is it possible to implement OAuth 2.0 with Google Sites API?

Tags: c#, oauth, google-api, google-sites

I try to find a method to access on a Google Site website with OAuth method. Today I can access to my site with a basic authentication (Google.GData.Client, username/password) but I didn't found documentation, tutorials or questions about this protocol.

I work with .Net library, and with C# language.

Is it possible, or not ?

Thanks by advance,

Azuken

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try the [Google.Apis.SiteVerification.v1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.SiteVerification.v1/) client library from Google.  If you install the NuGet package it will automatically install all you will need to deal with authentication as well.

Note: I'm not 100% sure this is the right file.  There is a list of the APIs that the client lib work with here [Google APIs Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/siteVerification/v1)

The only example I have on hand for Oauth with C# uses the Google Drive API you will have to change it a little.

You need to find the correct scopes to use with Google Site

```
UserCredential credential; 
 credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
              new ClientSecrets { ClientId = "YourClientId", ClientSecret = "YourClientSecret" },
              new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
              "user",
              CancellationToken.None,
              new FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")).Result; }
```

Once you have authenticated you just have to create a service that all of your requests get sent to. Again this creates a Google Drive service.

```
BaseClientService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
 {
 HttpClientInitializer = credential,
 ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
 });
```

Sorry that I don't have code specific for the API you are using, but I hope this helps you a little.